# 7 tables connected to one model class in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is my first time working in Spring. I am working on a webapp that will intake all needed information on one screen and sort out the data to its appropriate insert statements. I have 7 inserts that all correspond to their own respective tables but only 1 model file. I was wondering if having all information in one model is possible, and if so, how can I implement this?

```
public class Metadata implements Serializable{
  String app_nm
  String schdlr_nm
  String btch_nm
  String dir_nm
  String etl_nm
  String enc
  String file_nm
  String schema_nm
  String path
  String tbl_nm
  String ext
  String obj_nm
  ....
}
```

**scheduler_tbl** - app_nm, schdlr_nm
**batch_tbl** - btch_nm, dir_nm
**job_tbl** - btch_nm, etl_nm
**jobparam_tabl** - btch_nm, enc, file_nm
**dataobj_tbl** - obj_nm, btch_nm, schema_nm
**file_ptrn_tbl** - path, tbl_nm, ext, obj_nm
**optional_tbl** - app_nm, btch_nm, obj_nm

Comment: You should have 7 entity classes annoted `@Entity`, fetch data from these entities in a business service and merge them in your single Metadata model.
Then you should be able to return your Metadata model via one HTTP call using a Spring `@Controller` class.